# Disable request logging for a particular Go-Gin route

Tags: go, go-gin

I have a bunch of routes and start off gin with `gin.Default()` (enabling logging and recovery for all routes by default). But there is one route (i.e. `/health`) that gets pinged every 5 seconds. What's a straightforward way to disable request logging for that one route without changing much of the code?

```
func main() {
    // gin is initialized upstream in our internal framework
    // so I can't change this line easily.
    router := gin.Default()

    router.GET("/someGet", getting)
    router.POST("/somePost", posting)
    router.PUT("/somePut", putting)
    router.DELETE("/someDelete", deleting)
    // ... and more

    // Disable request logging for only this route. 
    // Note: I'm hoping that there's some parameter I can pass in here to do that
    route.GET("/health", health)

    router.Run()

}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`gin.Logger()` has a longer form with args that can take in args of strings listing paths that should not be logged, i.e. `gin.LoggerWithWriter(gin.DefaultWriter, "<NO LOG PATH 1>", ...)`.

I overwrote the base struct GinService with, `baseService.GinEngine = gin.New()` and then attached gin.LoggerWithWriter(...) and gin.Recovery() middlewares manually.

That did the trick.

Answer (score 22):

@Paul Lam's solution works! heres the code for reference:

```
    router := gin. Default()
```

Becomes

```
    router := gin.New()
    router.Use(
        gin.LoggerWithWriter(gin.DefaultWriter, "/pathsNotToLog/"),
        gin.Recovery(),
    )
```

`gin.Default()` definition referred from `github.com/gin-gonic/gin@v1.3.0/gin.go`

Answer (score 7):

There is also a `gin.LoggerWithConfig` middleware:

```golang
router.Use(gin.LoggerWithConfig(gin.LoggerConfig{SkipPaths: []string{"/static"}}))
```

```golang
type LoggerConfig struct {
    // Optional. Default value is gin.defaultLogFormatter
    Formatter LogFormatter

    // Output is a writer where logs are written.
    // Optional. Default value is gin.DefaultWriter.
    Output io.Writer

    // SkipPaths is a url path array which logs are not written.
    // Optional.
    SkipPaths []string
}
```