# Avoid 404 on root route using Gin

Tags: go, go-gin

I am working on a CMS project where the URL for the frontend is `https://cms.example.com`

However, the backend routes start with `/v1` which I have configured in gin as a Router Group `engine.Group("/v1")`. Hence a backend endpoint will be something like `https://cms.example.com/v1/endpoint`

I've also set a `NoRoute` handler function:

```golang
var errRouteNotFound = errors.New("route not found")
s.engine.NoRoute(func(c *gin.Context) {
 c.AbortWithError(http.StatusNotFound, errRouteNotFound)
})
```

The issue I am facing is that whenever someone visits the frontend, I get a 404 error for GET request on `/` in the backend logs. How can I avoid getting these logs without changing the route schema as it's part of a bigger project?

Edit: I am using a custom logger.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable request logging for a particular Go-Gin route](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48780070/disable-request-logging-for-a-particular-go-gin-route)

Comment: @EmilePels I'm using a custom logger so this won't work.

Comment: then you're not going to get a helpful answer without supplying more information about that. This question is not about Gin, but about your "custom logger".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution:

#### In case gin's logger is used

Use this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56053139/3742786). Thanks to @EmilePels.

#### In case of a custom logger

Use something like this in the logger function:

```golang
requestURL := c.Request.URL.String()
if requestURL == "/" {
  return
}
```